# Android Studio hangs when drag/dropping UI element

Tags: android, android-studio

I installed Android Studio 1.0 and have JDK 1.8.

I make New Project, use a 'blank activity with fragment' and set the minimum version to lollipop (5.0)

Then I go to fragment_main.xml and drag an UI element to the phone (in the example i used a button)

The moment the drag interface is visible on the phone, android studio hangs and i'm unable to do anything expect killing the process with windows taskmanager.

[image]

My mouse looks like this:

[image]

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: I briefly checked out Android Studio 1.0 for OSX today and encountered a few severe lags and moments where the thing got hung up for 30 seconds or so.  I think maybe I'll stick with Eclipse a little longer.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue but in Linux Mint

Answer (score 6):

I may have found a solution for this.

I was having the same exact issue and couldn't figure out what was going on for the life of me until:

I theorized that perhaps it was just the windows display that was frozen (the visual rendering of the Android Studio program itself) and guessed that perhaps this was using a DirectX device to do the rendering of the Android UI.

I happen to have another app running on my computer that uses a DirectX device for rendering (SimpleJungleTimer, an app I programmed with a DirectX overlay for League of Legends jungle timers). After I shut down this app Android Studio appears to be working properly (not freezing when working with the UI anymore)

Ultimately it sounds like this is a bug with Android Studio itself where they don't properly kill / reload the DirectX rendering device when it is in conflict with another app's active DirectX device (something that the android studio developers should probably fix), however until the android studio developers fix this you should be able to **get around this bug by making sure any other applications that might use DirectX for rendering are shut down while coding in Android Studio** so that their DirectX rendering devices don't conflict with Android Studio's DirectX device.

Answer (score 0):

There are also problem with Java 8 in Mac OSX. When any drag and drop I made result in hanging the Android Studio 2.0 preview. This problem also happen to me when I use intellij 15.
You can have a look at this link: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-146691.

I switch the JDK use in may projects to Java 7 and the drag and drop feature works. You can do the switch by choose **File** > **Project Structure** > Change in your JDK location.