# Android Studio hangs out

Tags: android, android-studio

Whenever, I take Time Picker and Date Picker in XML layout file in Android studio.

Android studio hangs out.

Which configuration changes i need to do? Please help me.

Comment: There is 12GB RAM in my PC.

Comment: File -> Invalidates Caches/Restart.  (After Clean and rebuild your project)

Comment: try to clean & run...

Comment: What is your sdk level?

Comment: try using android:datePickerMode="spinner"

Comment: While i drag and drop time picker its hangs. I can't change any thing. Mostly in Time Picker.

Comment: @MayuriJoshi Avoid Drag and drop .Too bad approach .

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya I try it but still hanging.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27430865/android-studio-hangs-when-drag-dropping-ui-element

Comment: Instead of drag and drop, try implementing it in the xml along with android:datePickerMode="spinner"

Comment: @MayuriJoshi Which version ? 1.4 stable .

Comment: I m using Android Studio version 1.3.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**@Mayuri Joshi**

Courtesy goes to @Wootowl's [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27430865/android-studio-hangs-when-drag-dropping-ui-element) .

> I theorized that perhaps it was just the windows display that was
>   frozen (the visual rendering of the Android Studio program itself) and
>   guessed that perhaps this was using a DirectX device to do the
>   rendering of the Android UI.
>
> I happen to have another app running on my computer that uses a
>   DirectX device for rendering (SimpleJungleTimer, an app I programmed
>   with a DirectX overlay for League of Legends jungle timers). After I
>   shut down this app Android Studio appears to be working properly (not
>   freezing when working with the UI anymore)
>
> Ultimately it sounds like this is a bug with Android Studio itself
>   where they don't properly kill / reload the DirectX rendering device
>   when it is in conflict with another app's active DirectX device
>   (something that the android studio developers should probably fix) .

### What should you do

1. ***Avoid Drag and drop Facility***
2. **Use Stable Android Studio (Like Version 1.3)** Avoid Beta Version .
3. *File -> Invalidates Caches/Restart. (After Clean and rebuild your project)*

Comment: When i do coding inside xml file it does't hangs. But when i what to see preview it hangs.