# Android Studio stop working when edit XML layout file

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

When i try to edit `XML` layout files in **Android Studio** in visual mode. **Android Studio** stop working and i can't do anything .

I test more and more times and reinstalling of android studio didn't solve this problem.

Whether you've had this problem in **Android Studio** ?

how can i solve this issue ?

My System is **Windows 8.1**

In this screenshot **Android Studio** hanged up :

[image]

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/27726594/5038993

Comment: what jdk version do you have? How much of RAM your computer has?

Comment: my computer ram is 8GB DDR3 and jdk is 1.7